# How do I set print options for lpr command within a Python script?

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, cups, lpr

When I run `lpr <filename>.jpg` the file prints out boderless (this is what I want).

When I run `subprocess.call("/usr/bin/lpr " + tmp.name, shell=True)` from a Python program, it prints out with borders.

I also tried to call it with "lpr -o StpBorderless=True -o StpiShrinkOutput=Expand .jpg" with the same borders still being printed.

Output from `lpoptions` shows the below (`StpBorderless=True`, and `StpiShrinkOutput=Expand` should make it borderless I think).

How can I execute `lpr` from a Python script to use the exact same options as if I executed it from command line?

```
auth-info-required=none
copies=1
device-uri=usb://Canon/CP800?serial=DH00071100000840
finishings=3
job-hold-until=no-hold
job-priority=50
job-sheets=none,none
marker-change-time=0
number-up=1
printer-commands=none
printer-info='Canon CP800'
printer-is-accepting-jobs=true
printer-is-shared=false
printer-location printer-make-and-model='Canon SELPHY-CP770 - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.9'
printer-state=3
printer-state-change-time=1433298534
printer-state-reasons=none printer-type=2134028
printer-uri-supported=ipp://localhost:631/printers/Canon_CP800
StpBorderless=True
StpiShrinkOutput=Expand
```

Comment: are you sure that you are using the same lpr in both cases?  What is the output of 'which lpr' in the command line?

Comment: I made sure it was the same one, which lpr shows it at /usr/bin/lpr

Comment: When I test the print command from the command line it is actually, "lpr <filename>.jpg", but from python it is actually a tmp file (from a tempFile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) call. There is no extension so it is simply, "lpr tmpnzt4mE".  Could that have any affect.  I can't check until I get home.